# Attach file to list in Sandbox Webpart

Tags: sandbox-solution

I am trying to create a custom control for updating a List on a Sharepoint site that only allows Sandbox Solutions to be added.

I've read a few threads on uploading attachments, but they all seem to involve doing it from the server machine (Using a file stream to read a local file).

Is it not possible to use Javascript or something to pass a file through to a Sandbox'd webpart??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not particularly, as the code you'll need to execute in the sandbox will be running in the sandboxed process, and this doesn't allow access to System.IO, which you will need in order to create a FileStream which represents the file you're uploading and is written to a new item in the list.